# Как boost::filesystem::directory_entry::path() добавить в const char **

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, файловая-система, boost

Доброе время суток.
Есть класс, у него есть член

```
const char **_files_container;
```

Если я правильно понимаю, это массив "си строк".
В конструкторе я инициализирую этот массив

```
this->_files_container = new const char*[10];
```

Таким образом, я могу положить в него 10 штук const char[];

Далее я пользуюсь библиотекой boost::filesystem, шарю по папке и найденные файлы просто хочу в виде текста закинуть в этот самый `_files_container`

Тут я сталкиваюсь с проблемой:

```
itr->path().string();
```

Вернет строку, как и нужно, но типа `string`, а мне нужно получается `const char*;`

Хорошо, я умею преобразовать такие разногласия с помощью `c_str()`:

```
this->_files_container[0] = itr->path().string().c_str();
```

И вот тут самый затык. Вывожу в консоль `cout << this->_files_container[0] << endl;` и получаю.. просто графические артефакты какие-то, либо пусто, либо просто буква *e*.

Если заполнить массив руками, например:

```
this->_files_container[0] = "Fire in the hole!";
```

То всё работает как надо.

Что я упускаю или не знаю, подскажите в чём проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Правильное решение

Вместо `const char **_files_container;` создать `std::vector<std::string> _files_container` и не мучатся.

## Мазохистское решение

Вручную управлять памятью и копировать строки в `char[]`

```
std:: string path=itr->path().string();
this->_files_container[0] = new char [path.size()+1];
strcpy( this->_files_container[0], itr->path().string().c_str());
```

В этом случае кроме всего прочего надо не забыть **самостоятельно** удалить память, когда она уже не будет нужна.

## Почему так происходит

Строка возвращаемая из `tr->path().string()` является временным объектов и удаляется по завершении оператора. соответственно когда позже кто-то пытается обратиться по указателю на эту память там уже содержится мусор.

Comment: Спасибо за два решения. Цель - написать прогу именно по заветам "старой школы", поэтому воспользовался мазохистским решением. Зашло с одной оговоркой - пишу в MS VS, и студия всегда ругается на strcpy, предлагая использовать либо strcpy_s, либо флаг _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. strcpy_s не захотела копировать выкидывая исключения и ссылаясь что-то на template, с флагом заработало как надо. Что тут порекомендуете? Пишут, что strcpy_s это чисто MS фишка, а strcpy это классика. На линуксе strcpy_s не взлетит я так понял?

Comment: лол, использование `boost`'а — это уже далеко не oldscool, ну да ладно... Про `strcpy_s`, фактически — чисто MS'овская... хотя сейчас оно пропихнуто в качестве опционального расширения стандарта С11, но, на сколько я знаю, пока ни одна libc в *nix мире её не поддерживает... Моё мнение — почти все `*_s` версии — контрпродуктивны, а те что имеют смысл, имеют POSIX аналоги. Да, за правильное использование strcpy ответственность лежит на программисте...

Answer (score 1):

Вызов `path().string()` может возвращать временную строку, соответственно после выполнения этого выражения она будет разрушена, а сохраненный указатель станет невалидным. Сохраняйте возвращенные строки в векторе:

```
::std::vector<::std::string> _files_container;

_files_container.emplace_back(itr->path().string());
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по `itr->path().string()`, вы обходите циклом директорию и итераторы у вас умирают на каждой итерации, а указатели на их данные повисают. Пытаясь потом прочесть данные из битого указателя, вы получаете случайный вывод.

Вам необходимо скопировать строки к себе в `_files_container`.